# mapping reductions from R to RE

Tags: turing-machines, reductions

Let $L_1$ be some language in $R$. Let $L_2$ be some language in $RE$. Is it necessarily that
$L_1 \leq_m L_2$ ?
I know that for non trivial $L_1$,$L_1$ in $R$ it is right to say that $L_1 \leq_m L_2$.
But I can't prove the first case.

and another question:
I am almost certain that the following is true, though I have not found any reference to it on the Internet:
The identity function is a mapping reduction from $\emptyset$ to $\emptyset$.

Comment: Unfold the definitions, you don't need the internet to tell if the identity function is a reduction from a language to itself. Think about what happens if $L_1$ or $L_2$ are trivial.

Comment: Have you read my question? I wrote that for *non trivial*

Comment: Can you state precisely what restrictions, if any,  you have on $L_1$ and $L_2$?

Comment: I don't have any restrictions. When talking about reductions we say that $L_1\leq_mL_2$ means (in a way) that " $L_1$ is easier than $L_2$". I'm trying to figure out if there is a mapping reduction from any $L_1$  to any $L_2$  that is "harder". In the original question I refer to the private case, where the easier class is $R$ and the hardest one is $RE$

Comment: If you have no restrictions on $L_2$ then the claim is false. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If $L_2 \neq \Sigma^*$ and $L_2 \neq \emptyset$ then $L_1 \in R$ and $L_2 \in RE$ implies $L_1 \le_m L_2$.**

Let $T$ be a Turing machine that decides $L_1$. Let $a,b \in \Sigma^*$ such that $a \in L_2$ and $b \not\in L_2$.
For $x \in \Sigma^*$, define $\phi(x) =
\begin{cases}
a & \text{ if $T(x)$ accepts }\\
b & \text{ if $T(x)$ rejects }
\end{cases}$.
It is easy to check that $\phi$ is a mapping reduction from $L_1$ to $L_2$.

**If $L_2 = \Sigma^*$ then $L_1 \in R$ and $L_2 \in RE$ does not imply $L_1 \le_m L_2$.**

This can be seen, e.g., by choosing $L_1 = \emptyset$.

**If $L_2 = \emptyset$ then $L_1 \in R$ and $L_2 \in RE$ does not imply $L_1 \le_m L_2$.**

This can be seen, e.g., by choosing $L_1 = \Sigma^*$.

Comment: thank you very much!